# Can't copy files from network drive

Tags: windows, windows-xp, network-shares, file-transfer

I have weird problem with copying files.

When I copy file from network drive into C drive nothing happens but when I copy file from network drive to desktop I can copy the file. Also if I copy files from desktop into C it works fine.

I have full local admin permission on this PC and the network drive.

I have try these things

- Created new profile
- Run Windows Update
- Run checkdisk

I'm using Windows XP 32bit pro

**Update:**

*Network path:*

\\server1\shared\folder

*PC:*

C:\ (this doesn't work)

C:\Documents and settings\Userid\Desktop (This works fine)

Comment: Considering the Desktop folder is on the system drive ( normally ) your statmeent makes little sense you might want to clarify it.  Provide full path names if you would

Comment: Are you performing this in the command line or are you using the regular Windows Explorer GUI?

Comment: Please elaborate on 'nothing happens', or maybe upload a screenshot if possible.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus regular Windows Explorer GUI

Comment: Is this your personal computer or a company computer?

Answer (score -1):

Under Drive Properties of `C:`, see if `Network File and Folder Sharing` is enabled.

`Computer -> C:\ -> Properties -> Sharing -> SHARE`

Might work.